# Implementing the tails function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement the function [`tails`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=tails). This is my attempt:

```
tails' :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails' [] = []
tails' (x:xs) = xs:[[tails' xs]]
```

I keep running into compilation errors:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[[a]]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for tails' :: [a] -> [[a]] at..
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: By your type signature, `tails' xs` must already be a list of lists. Enclosing it in brackets as `[[tails' xs]]` wraps that list of lists in two extra singleton lists. All you need is `tails' (x:xs) = xs:tails' xs`.

Comment: @Alec : You are right. It works. But I still don't get it why the brackets should be removed (aside from the fact that it makes the program work:)). Isn't it the job of the programmer to ensure that the returned value matches the one in type signature?? Because the way you are putting : type signature takes care of converting it into a list of lists

Comment: (1) Closely related: [*Why doesn't this function work if I use “\[xs\]” instead of “xs”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48884276/2751851) (2) While the answer you have accepted covers your immediate issue, its solution is wrong -- for instance, `tails [] = [[]]` and `head (tails xs) = xs` are supposed to hold. I recommend switching the accept mark to another answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
tails' (x:xs) = xs:[[tails' xs]]
```

with:

```
tails' (x:xs) = xs : tails' xs
```

Comment: You don't even need the parens: `xs : tails' xs` works fine.

Comment: @Leandro Galvan : Can you please explain why you removed the brackets?

Comment: @Ashwin the term `tails' xs` without the brackets is already a list of lists, i.e., of type `[[a]]`. It's a little confusing because the function is recursive, but if you look at the type you declared, it reads __tails' takes a list and returns a list of lists__; since `xs` is a list, applying it to `tails'` yields a list of lists.

Comment: another quibble - to be the same as `Data.List.tails`, `head (tails xs) == xs`

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the <s>syntax</s> type error, your implementation is not correct (to the spec).  Compare it with this one...

```
Prelude> let tails [] = [[]]
Prelude|     tails y@(x:xs) = y:(tails xs)
Prelude|
Prelude> tails "abc"
["abc","bc","c",""]
```

Comment: Even your implementation is not to-spec. Compare the result of `null (tails undefined)` between your implementation and `Data.List`'s.

Comment: @DanielWagner I see how the implementation in Data.List manages to return `False` for that input, but why is it a useful property that `tails undefined = undefined : tails (tail undefined)`?

Comment: @amalloy Let me turn the question around on you: why is it useful to be more strict than necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It's been over a year now but no correct answers were given so here's my take on it.

Let's start with the type signature:

```
tails' :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

This sugests that `tails'` should return a list-of-lists. The terminal case you syggested is just an empty list. Change it to:

```
tails' [] = [[]]
```

Now, the general case. Let's *assume* that our `tails'` works the way we want it to:

```
tails' []      -> [[]]
tails' [1]     -> [[1], []]
tails' [2,1]   -> [[2,1], [1], []]
tails' [3,2,1] -> [[3,2,1], [2,1], [1], []]
```

As we can see, we want to include the original list and the empty list. This means that given an input list `xs`, we want to concatenate `xs` onto *something else*.

But what's that *something else*? Let's do a bit of pseudo-haskell math:

```
let A = tails' [3,2,1] = [[3,2,1], [2,1], [1], []]
let B = tails' [2,1] = [[2,1], [1], []]
=> A = [[3,2,1], B] -- (1)

tail [3,2,1] == [2,1]
=> B = tails' (tail [3,2,1]) -- (2)

By (1) and (2)
A = [[3,2,1], tails' (tail [3,2,1])]
=> tails' [3,2,1] = [[3,2,1], tails' (tail [3,2,1])] -- (3)

By replacing [3,2,1] in (3) with xs
tails' xs = [xs, tails' (tail xs)]
```

Translating all this into Haskell gives us:

```
tails' :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails' [] = [[]]
tails' xs = xs : (tails' $ tail xs)


main = do
  print $ tails' [1,2,3]

-- [[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, I'm not sure that "no correct answers [had been] given". The solution you arrive at is essentially the same as [the one by karafka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448891/2751851), down to the detail about strictness mentioned by Daniel Wagner.

Answer (score 1):

`tails` is the canonical example with simple lists for the recursion scheme called *paramorphism*. The following example uses the [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) library from Edward Kmett:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.List (tails)                      -- just for our test

paratails :: [a] ->  [[a]]
paratails = para alg where
    alg :: ListF a ([a], [[a]]) -> [[a]]
    alg (Cons x (hs, res)) = (x : hs) : res
    alg Nil = [[]]

-- $
-- >>> paratails [1,2,3,4]
-- [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4],[]]
-- >>> paratails []
-- [[]]
-- >>> paratails [1,2,3,4] == (tails [1,2,3,4])
-- True
-- >>> paratails [] == (tails [])
-- True
```

Note: To shorten the code, you may use *LambdaCase*. With this extension, however, you cannot specify the type signature of the *alg* function

Comment: "With [`LambdaCase`], however, you cannot specify the type signature of the alg function" -- I tried that over here and it worked fine (I kept the `alg` definition in the `where` clause, though).

Answer (score 1):

As there now is a *recursion-schemes* fold answer, I feel obliged to add a *recursion-schemes* unfold answer:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

tailsApo :: [a] -> [[a]]
tailsApo = apo coalgTails
    where
    coalgTails = \case
        [] -> Cons [] (Left [])
        li@(_:xs) -> Cons li (Right xs)
```

I have used an apomorphism instead of a plain anamorphism because we don't want to produce an empty list out of an empty list (`tails [] == [[]]`).