# Why doesn't this function work if I use "[xs]" instead of "xs"?

Tags: haskell

```
split :: [a] -> Int -> ([a], [a])
split [xs] n = 
    (take n [xs], drop n [xs])
```

The same code works if I give the variable as `xs` instead of `[xs]`, signatures are same in both cases. Using `[xs]` gives the error that pattern is non-exhaustive. I understand it's telling that the input I gave is not covered by my code, but not clear what is happening under the hood.

Test input: `[1,2,3] 2`.

Comment: Well `[xs]` matches a list with *exactly* one element, and that element is then unified with `xs`. Somehow people ask this question every other day :(

Comment: In the future, please try to give your questions more specific titles. "Haskell code doesn't work, why?" says almost nothing about your problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree, this error is way too frequent here on SO. We might need to write a "reference" question/answer, addressing the general issue, so that we can close all such questions as duplicates. We did that for the monomorphism restriction (after a bit of discussion on meta, IIRC).

Comment: I have a counter-question: why would you expect `[xs]` to mean the same thing as `xs`?

Comment: @DanielWagner I do not expect [xs] to mean same thing as xs, however as mentioned (comments in ans) below the primary confusion came as in Haskell when declaring types you use [] for list. That plus since I do not frequently use Haskell so as default wrote the code like that. As mentioned in the question I knew how to get the code working and understood partly what the compiler was complaining but still could not get the overall picture. Thanks for answers now I know a little bit more. Maybe adding this as a reference question answer is a good idea.

Comment: See also [*Pattern matching expects round braces for non empty list and not square brackets*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49831324/2751851) for extra discussion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Somehow a lot of people think that `[xs]` as pattern means that you *unify* a list with `xs`. But this is incorrect, since the function signature (either derived implicitly, or stated explicitly) already will prevent you to write code where you call the function with a non-list item.

A list has *two* constructors:

- the empty list `[]`; and
- the "cons" `(h : t)` with `h` the *head* (first element), and `t` the *tail* (a list with the remaining elements).

Haskell however introduces some syntactical sugar as well. For example `[1]` is short for `(1:[])`, and `[1, 4, 2]` for `(1:(4:(2:[])))`.

So that means that if you write `[xs]`, behind the curtains you defined a pattern `(xs: [])` which thus means you match all lists with *exactly* one element, and that single *element* (not the entire list) is then `xs`.

Anyway, the solution is to use:

```
split xs n = (take n xs, drop n xs)
```

Since both [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) and [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop) have in the signature that `xs` is supposed to be a list, Haskell will derive automatically that `n` is supposed to be an `Int`, and `xs` an `[a]`.

Note that you can use [**`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) as well. We can make the signature equivalent to the one you target with:

```
split = flip splitAt
```

Comment: I actually liked your comment more since that explained me the (or my) issue very clearly. Think probably this a typical beginner problem, partly due to the fact that in a function signature [a] would mean a list while the same ([a]) in code means a list containing a single value!

Comment: @peeyushsingh Yeah, the "`[]`-the-type vs `[]`-the-value" pun can confuse beginners. You have to remember that types and values live in different worlds. When you define `data Foo = Foo`, the left-hand side defines a type named `Foo` and the right-hand side defines a value which coincidentally happens also to be named `Foo` (but in a different namespace). That's just the same as what's going on with `[]` and `[]`.

Comment: @peeyushsingh: You can think of the type `[a]` as syntactic sugar for the normal prefix syntax `[] a`—which you can use instead, just like other prefix type constructors such as `Maybe a`. It’s just visually nicer to write `[[Int]]` than `[] ([] Int)`, for example.