# Haskell:Non-exhaustive patterns in function bean

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I get non exhaustive patterns exception for the following code

```
bean :: [a] -> Int -> a
bean [a] b = last $ take (b + 1) [a]
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884276/why-does-this-function-doesnt-work-if-i-use-xs-instead-of-xs/48884382#48884382 (sigh)

Comment: bean :: [a] -> Int -> a
bean a b = last $ take (b + 1) a