# Why is ["",_] not the same as ("":_)?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have stumbled across an error that was very confusing to me. I had a recursive function with the pattern matching `["",_] = []` which simply didnt work. After many times of trying to find my mistake I tried switching it up with `("":_) = []`. And it worked! I just want to know why the first term didnt work but the second one did.
This function works and the pattern matching is called:

```
takeAllElem :: [String] -> [String]
takeAllElem ("":_) = []
takeAllElem (xs) =  map takeFirstElem (xs) :  (takeAllElem (removeFirstElem (xs)))
```

This function also works but the pattern matching is never called:

```
takeAllElem :: [String] -> [String]
takeAllElem ["",_] = []
takeAllElem (xs) =  map takeFirstElem (xs) :  (takeAllElem (removeFirstElem (xs)))
```

Is this just a syntax error or does the compiler interpret `["",_]` differently to `("":_)`.

Comment: `["",_]` is equivalent to `("":__:[])`.

Comment: ...or `"":[_]`.

Comment: Closely related: [*Why doesn't this function work if I use "\[xs\]" instead of "xs"?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48884276/2751851)

Comment: You might like [`transpose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose).

Comment: because `[` is not `(`.

Answer (score 8):

`["", _]` is a list containing *exactly* two elements, equivalent to `"":_:[]`.

`("":_)` is any non-empty list whose first element is the empty string. The tail is an arbitrary list.

Comment: "an arbitrary list" ... of `String`s.